# Yii : data is not passed to view

Tags: php, yii, widget, yii-components

Having this widget class:

```
class ValuesSetWidget extends CWidget {

public $id = null;
public $listHtmlOptions = array();
public $addDivClasses = "";
public $model;
public $attribute;
public $name;
public $value;

public function init()
{
    //registramos script básico
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile('/js/JSON.js');

    $name = ($this->model) ? get_class($this->model).'-'.$this->attribute : $this->name;
    $this->id = ($this->id) ? $this->id : 'id'.$name;

    return $this->render('application.widgets.ValuesSet.widget', array('context' => $this), true);
}

}
```

And being this view the one being invoked:

```
<?php
$id = $context->id;
$buttonid = $id.'-button';
$hiddenid = $id.'-hidden';
$selectid = $id.'-select';
$dialogid = $id.'-dialog';
$htformid = $id.'-form';
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->getClientScript()->getCoreScriptUrl().'/jui/css/'.(isset($theme) ? $theme : 'base').'/jquery-ui.css');
?>
<!-- more html/php for the view here... -->
```

I get an error like this:

[image: Variable not defined. ¿Data not being passed?]

**Question**: Why is the $context not being passed when I pass data with render() to the widget view?
**Goal**: I need to pass the entire context to the view file.

Comment: The screenshot and posted code do not match. (Screenshot refers to $this_, which is an obvious typo.) Also, $this in the view file refers to the renderer, which in this case is the widget, so there is no need to pass 'context'. Lastly, rendering code is usually placed in run(), not init().

Comment: sorry, updated 'this_' to 'context' later. did not update the screenshot. the error was not in $this_, was in other part of the code. (when got the error on the first time, i had an error on assigning "this" as key. then I got a context error and renamed the variable to 'this_' (and so, $this_); finally due to a suggestion I changed this_ to context. In the whole process, did not update the screenshot).

Comment: Sent an answer to explain this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code did not included everything affected. However, the error message is your clue.

Instead of

```
 $id = $this_->id
```

use

```
 $id = $this->id
```

in widget.php

Comment: sorry, updated 'this_' to 'context' later. did not update the screenshot. the error was not in $this_, was in other part of the code. (when got the error on the first time, i had an error on assigning "this" as key. then I got a context error and renamed the variable to 'this_' (and so, $this_); finally due to a suggestion I changed this_ to context. In the whole process, did not update the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry :p. The error was not in that code.

It never worked ($this, $this_, nor $context) because **I referenced the view file, erroneously, fom the createWidget() call** (instead of referencing the widget's class file, I referenced the widget's view file). This caused the file to be imported/required, and thus sent to output but without ANY data (because no data was passed to widget creation).

Finally was not true problem with variable names, because neither of them existed at all - It was the wrong file reference.

Comment: Thanks for posting back, and well done on finding the solution. Sure feels good when you learn a few things along the way.

Comment: It feels terrible when the learnt stuff was about something like that, instead of a kind of internal issue or true bug. Makes me want to shoot my right foot xD.